# Football counter with jquery

Tags: jquery, counter

:-)
Anyone know how to make a sort of counter, so when i click "Start match", the counter begin to go from 00:00:01 to 00:00:02 and so on, untill it reach 00:90:00 (the length of a football game).

Hope someone can help me.

Best Regards,
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a couple references

[Flipcounter](http://bloggingsquared.com/jquery/flipcounter/)

[Stopwatch](http://www.kellishaver.com/projects/stopwatch/)